# ReachabilityCreateWithAddress struct in_addr, ip-format

Tags: objective-c, ios6, reachability

I'm want to write an ip-check with the reachability.h and reachability.m from apples sample code.

I want to use this function:

```
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) ipAddress;
```

So it gets an sockaddr_in structure.

I get so far:

```
struct sockaddr_in ipAddress;
    ipAddress.sin_len = sizeof(ipAddress);
    ipAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ipAddress.sin_port = 80;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr = ???; //???
    char        sin_zero[8];
```

The ip address is a struct, too.

```
struct in_addr {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
};


typedef __uint32_t      in_addr_t;  /* base type for internet address */
```

But how I can put an ip address in the struct?
Which format i got to use? E.g. 192.168.2.2 doesn't work.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inet_pton()` (defined in `<arpa/inet.h>`) to convert a string containing
a network address to network format. And note that you have to convert the port
number from host byte order to network byte order:

```
struct sockaddr_in ipAddress;
ipAddress.sin_len = sizeof(ipAddress);
ipAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
ipAddress.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.2.2", &ipAddress.sin_addr);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out. But that did not work for me.
It doesn't matter what for a string I put in as an ip address. Everything is reachable. E.g. "BlaBlabla"

Comment: @shizophren: I just noticed that you forgot to convert the port number to network byte order (see updated answer).

Comment: @shizophren: Have a look at the SCNetworkReachability documentation: *"A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host."*

Comment: So what can I do, to check weather a service e.g. on a webserver (ip + port) is reachable? The reachabilityCreateWithName works as expected.

Comment: @shizophren: You have to create a connection to check if server responds on that port. You can use the low-level BSD function connect(), or higher level functions such as CFStream. The "CFNetwork Programming Guide" might help.